# I want to copy data from a text box under Settings, but drag and drop doesn't work. Is there a quick way to do it which is not OCR-ing the screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, icloud

[image]
This is the text box. They're iCloud abbreviations.

I want to export them, but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know if there is a way to do it through the UI.

Good news, though, is that this is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`. Here is a way to extract the information into a CSV file that you can open into a spreadsheet:

1. Open Terminal
2. Copy and paste the following line:

   ```
   defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems | gawk '/replace|with/ {s = substr($0, index($0, "= ")+2 ); gsub(";", "", s); printf "%s, ", s }; /^ *with/ {printf "\n"};' > text.csv
   ```
3. Open `text.csv` with Numbers, LibreOffice, or Excel.

Comment: Yayyy!!! Thank you! You saved my life. I have more than 1000 abbreviations saved and I'm about to switch to an android phone. This means a lot!